# Link prediction on completely edgeless graphs

Tags: machine-learning, graph-neural-network

All existing link prediction methods (and indeed, all GNN methods in general) rely on edges being present in the input graph, and the method would be able to predict any missing edges. I've seen one paper called edgeless-GNN which explains how to perform link prediction on edgeless 'nodes', alongside an existing graph. My question is, is there a method for performing link prediction on a completely edgeless graph from scratch? Theoretically, I believe this should be possible using inductive methods. The assumption is that the network would be pre-trained on a different graph in the same domain.

Comment: Do the graphs used for pretraining have edges

Comment: @Janosch yes, all the edges would be present in the training graphs.